# React Native Shoutem UI Tool kit Icon not working

Tags: react-native, shoutem

[image: See the image]

Here you can see the icons are not loaded. Can someone please find me a solution.

**Code content:**

```
import {Icon, Row} from '@shoutem/ui';

return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <NavigationBar title="All Restaurants" />
                <View style={styles.row}>
                <Row styleName="small" >
                    <Icon name="play"/>
                    <Text>About</Text>
                    <Icon styleName="disclosure" name="right-arrow"/>
                </Row>
              </View>
            </View>
        );
```

Comment: This is problem is quite similar to this issue `https://github.com/shoutem/ui/issues/82`. Suggesting to use `Text` component from **shoutem** rather from **react-naitve**

Comment: no, its not working. I have issue with the Icon, not the Text component.

Comment: How do you run project? If you are not using `shoutem` CLI you have to execute `react-native link` command in your project root before running the app.

Answer (score 2):

For me this issue occurred because the font files were not in the `android/app/src/main/assests/font/` folder inside the root of your react-native directory.

I copied all the font files from [this link to shoutem's github](https://github.com/shoutem/ui/tree/develop/examples/RestaurantsApp/android/app/src/main/assets/fonts) (you may also find it inside your-project-directory/node_modules/@shoutem/ui/examples/RestaurentsApp/android/app/src/main/assests/font/) to the above folder and rebuilt the app.

This worked for me, I hope it'll work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's an issue with loading fonts. Could you check @shoutem/ui's Github for similar issues? There is one about icons appearing as Chinese letters. Did you try with other icon names?

Answer (score 0):

I know I am responding to an old thread, but as it shows up first in Google for I'm sure many people experiencing the same problem will come across this one.

I realized I forgot to run `react-native link` after `npm install @shoutem/ui --save`.

Skipping this step caused the fonts and assets (including icons) not to be installed. Running the link command fixed the missing fonts.